# how to pass props when routing to another page in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-props

I am building an e-commerce shop and want to pass the specific item object to dynamically render the product on its own page. I am having trouble doing so and have only been able to pass the props as a param in the router. I want to be able to pass the props to another page the same way like putting the whole object in the params. It works if i put the entire object in the params but then my URL is undesirable. Since i am not calling on the component directly from within the shop item page, I am unsure how to pass the props to the product page, how would i accomplish this?

any help is greatly appreciated.

router:

```
  {
    path: "/buy/:product",
    name: "Buy",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Buy" */ "../views/Buy.vue"),
    props: true,
  },
```

parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome To Our Shop</h1>
    <div class="products">
      <div v-for="product in products" v-bind:key="product.name">
        <div>
          <ShopItem v-bind:products="product" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ShopItem from "../components/Shop/ShopItem";
export default {
  name: "Shop",
  components: { ShopItem },
  data() {
    return {
      products: [
        {
          name: "Basic Deck",
          price: 7,
          description:
            "The Basic Deck includes 68 cards: 10 cards in each of six categories, three icon legend cards, five blank cards for developing your own backstory elements, and instructions.",
          image: require("@/assets/Draeorc.png")
        },
        {
          name: "Card Bundle",
          price: 10,
          description:
            "The Card Bundle includes the Basic Deck, Technical Booster, Mystical Booster and instructions as a single self-printable PDF.",
          image: require("@/assets/Twilight.png")
        },
        {
          name: "Full Bundle with Box",
          price: 12,
          description:
            "The Full Bundle includes the Basic Deck, Technical Booster, Mystical Booster, instructions and tuck box as a single self-printable PDF.",
          image: require("@/assets/Orig_Godbringer.png")
        },
        {
          name: "Technical Booster",
          price: 2,
          description:
            "The Technical Booster includes 10 new cards that focus on sci-fi and hi-tech concepts.  Also includes two blank cards for creating your own backstory elements.",
          image: require("@/assets/Andrea_the_Sharp.png")
        },
        {
          name: "Mystical Booster ",
          price: 2,
          description:
            "The Mystical Booster includes 10 new cards that focus on magic and fantasy concepts.  Also includes two blank cards for creating your own backstory elements.",
          image: require("@/assets/Akmhenos_Courage.png")
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

shopItem:

```
<template>
  <div class="product-container">
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'Buy', params: {product: products.name } }">
      <div>
        <h2>
          {{ products.name }}
          <span class="price">${{ products.price }}</span>
        </h2>
        <div class="card-container">
          <img :src="products.image" alt="cards" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ShopItem",
  props: ["products"]
};
</script>
```

the page i want to pass the product to dynamically:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h1>{{product}}</h1>
      <div class="item-flex">
        <div class="card-wrapper">
          <img class="card-img" src="../assets/pdf.png" alt="pdf cards" />
        </div>
        <div class="item-desc">
          <h2></h2>
          <h2 class="price">$7</h2>
          <p>

          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button @click="submit" id="checkout-button">Checkout</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

</script>
```

Comment: How is the product object populated?  From a DB?  From a static file?

Comment: from its parent component... it is an array of objects.

Comment: i will eventually move it to my back end but for now i am storing the data on the front end

Comment: OK, I see.  I mean, it looks like you are passing the data down from the parent component fine, but its probably not a very good idea from an architectural point of view.  You could use a productName/productId so you can have a clean route and then use some kind of state management like Vuex to pull the rest of the information you need.  Otherwise, you will have to pass it down.  If you didn't want a full state management for now, you could just create a mock DB and put your products in a separate file and have each component that needed it access it.